# jqgrid getRowData(rowId) not returning proper value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have upgraded the jgrid from 3.7.2 to 4.4.4
from then onwards getRowData(rowId) is not working (ie not returning the row details)

my corresponding code snippet is

```
....
....
subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
...
var temprecord = new Array();
temprecord = jq("#dataGrid").getRowData(row_id);            
...
}
.....
```

In the above example

jqgrid 3.7.2 returns

```
temprecord : Object
name : abc
place : xyz
```

jqgrid 4.4.4 returns

```
temprecord as empty Object
```

I have also tried this variant  jq('#dataGrid').jqGrid('getRowData','row_id');
but even it does not work

Note: 
 In my grid, there were few columns that are not visible(not shown) to user.
In some forum, I remember I read that getRowData has a bug, when using in grid where some columns are not visible (display:none) to the user.

Is this true ? can anyone let me know how to getRowData using jgrid 4.4.4 version when grid contains some non visible columns

Comment: I suppose that the problem exist in the part of your code which you not posted. It would be good if you provide some demo (or simple demo code) which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oleg "SAME" code with jqgrid 3.7.2 is working fine. If I use jqgrid 4.4.4 with same code.. it is not working.

Comment: You should understand that code of jqGrid will be permanently changed. It's clear that **your old code is not compatible problem with new version of jqGrid**. So you should either debug your code yourself to find the problem or provide an example of the code which have the described compatibility problems. You can for example use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the code example.

Comment: If you not yet familiar with jsfiddler look [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrWkRHSK6A8) for example or just search in web for "jsfiddle tutorial"